# Implementation of dygraphs is performing poorly with large data sets

Tags: html, dygraphs

We are currently developing an application which uses [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com) for plotting data retrieved from a server at regular intervals (1 second).  dygraphs has served this application well and we have had no major issues with performance.  Now, we are trying to take large chunks of data (5 sets of 5000 points) and plot them on a single dygraph plot and the system seems to be bogging down in rendering the plot (taking on the order of 2 seconds to return).  From what I understand, dygrpahs should be fairly fast, so it is likely that I am doing something wrong.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to improve the performance of the application?

You can find a performance timeline [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lo-co/exscalabar/master/TimelineRawData-20160314T154830.json).

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

- You're using `dygraph-dev.js` rather than the production bundle. The dev version includes some debugging code that can slow down chart rendering.
- The profile indicates that each frame takes ~500ms to render. If you're seeing two second renders, then perhaps you're updating the charts too frequently.
- I see the dreaded "Not optimized: Optimized too many times" warning on the `stroke` calls. It would be interesting to see if this happened before.

It's hard to say much else without seeing a live demo.